# How to save canvas state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas, draw

I am implementing draw app, to draw a lines in canvas. The line is starting drawing on the first click and on mouse move the line is being drawn and on the second click, the drawing is stopping. When I click the third time the previously drawn line is disappearing. My requirement is I want to retain all of the lines. How do I do that? Below is my component code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function Canvas() {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  let startPosition: any = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let lineCoordinates: any = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let isDrawStart = false;
  let isFirstClick = false;
  let isSecondClick = false;

  const getClientOffset = (event: any) => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    const { pageX, pageY } = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
    const x = pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    const y = pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

    return {
      x,
      y,
    };
  };

  const drawLine = () => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if (context) {
      context.strokeStyle = "red";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 5;

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
      context.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
      context.stroke();
    }
  };

  const mouseClickListener = (event: any) => {
    if ((!isFirstClick && !isSecondClick) || (!isFirstClick && isSecondClick)) {
      isFirstClick = true;
      isSecondClick = false;
      startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
      isDrawStart = true;
      return;
    }
    if (isFirstClick && !isSecondClick) {
      isSecondClick = true;
      isFirstClick = false;
      isDrawStart = false;
    }
    console.log("First click", isFirstClick);
    console.log("Second click", isSecondClick);
  };

  const mouseMoveListener = (event: any) => {
    if (!isDrawStart) return;

    lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
    clearCanvas();
    drawLine();
  };

  const clearCanvas = () => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if (context) {
      context.save();
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.restore();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    canvas.addEventListener("click", mouseClickListener);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener);
  }, []);

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width="500"
      height="500"
      style={{ border: "1px solid black", marginTop: "50px" }}
    ></canvas>
  );
}
```

Comment: many ways to go but if you `clearCanvas()` I am not sure where is the surprise if the canvas get cleared each time ... you can either keep adding drawn lines on each mouseup and store initial point in mousedown, and re-draw all of them each time before adding the new one, or you can use toDataURL on drawn done and re-show the image with that data-url in the future as base to draw on top.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi Thanks for the suggestions, I save the coordinates of the lines in the array after the second mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

You can then use this variable to display it in a image, like so:

```
<img src={src} />
```